# How to sort by username when only userId is available using hql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hql

I am using hibernate with PostgreSQL database. I have two entity beans Task and User.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = TaskConstants.TASKSCHEMA, name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="assigned_to")
    private int assignedTo;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "assigned_to", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User assignedPerson;
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = TaskConstants.TASKSCHEMA, name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
}
```

I need to sort the tasks by fullname of the user using a single hql query. Someone please help.

Comment: Could you please describe what you did and where you are stuck im more detail? The query should not be too complicated - you just need an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Bascally i need a query like:
"from Task t order by t.assignedPerson.fullName"

Comment: exactly, this should do it

Comment: You can post your query as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HQL Query**

```
FROM Task AS t ORDER BY t.assignedPerson.fullName
```

HQL DOC

**[14.11. The order by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering)**